# Tornado coroutines inside websocket

Tags: python, python-requests, tornado

I've got Tornado setup to act as a Websocket server, and it works fine.

However, I'd like to take the incoming stream of data on the websocket, queue it up, and upload it to a second server via an HTTP POST request with chunked-transfer encoding in realtime.  I'm using the python requests library to do the POST (it supports getting the chunks from a generator).

Without coroutines, this does not work - as the upload method blocks execution, so new incoming data doesn't get added to the queue until after the upload has finished.

I added coroutines through some decorators in my websocket methods, but it doesn't work at all now - nothing gets uploaded via the HTTP POST.  I even tried adding a yield inside the make_request function like so (as "any function that calls a coroutine must be a coroutine itself, and use the yield keyword in the call" according to the Tornado docs):

```
data = yield self.read_queue()
```

but that threw a syntax error.
Example code is [here](http://pastebin.com/SZeL9ZGA).

I'm on Python 3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `requests` library is synchronous. You should not use it from Tornado except by running it in a thread. Using `requests` in a thread in this case would be trickier than the typical use of `ThreadPoolExecutor` in Tornado because you would be feeding data into it while it is running and you could have problems if a thread pool were exhausted.

Instead, use Tornado's `AsyncHTTPClient`. The `body_producer` argument allows you to upload the chunks as they come in.